# Does promotion in Checkers end a turn?

Tags: checkers

I've been playing checkers for quite some time. Recently a question arose which puzzled both of us:

[image: Can white keep going in the same turn?]

Can white move along the red line, i.e. eat the first black checker, reach the end, gain promotion, and then keep moving and eat two more checkers, or does promotion end the turn, with white remaining at the end?

I suppose the variant I play matches closest with English draughts, just with white starting.

Comment: You need to be specific about exactly which variant of "checkers" you are playing as there are [many, many variants which have different rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkers#National_and_regional_variants).

Comment: @philip-kendall Done. Thanks. Gosh, I had no idea there were THAT many!

Comment: Since the board you're showing is 12x12, wouldn't it be Canadian checkers? Canadian checkers follow the same rules as International checkers (10x10), meaning the piece will not be crowned but continues on to capture the other pieces.

Comment: @dennis-e You're quite right, however, I found some random online checkers game to illustrate the problem, that isn't the size board I play with. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Admittedly without citation, the [Wikipedia page for English draughts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_draughts#Kings) states:

> If a man moves into the kings row or if it jumps into the kings row, the current move terminates; the piece is crowned as a king but cannot jump back out as in a multi-jump until the next move.

The same "turn ends" rule can be found in e.g. the [WCDF Rules](https://www.usacheckers.com/downloads/WCDF_Revised_Rules.doc) available from the American Checker Federation.